# MATLAB fminunc gradient history

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am analyzing the optimization process of MATLAB's fminunc function.

Is there a way to obtain an array of gradient values in all the iterations ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. An [Output Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/output-function.html) should be used:

```
function optim_test
    grad_array= []; % initial array size is unknown
    f= @(x)x(1).^2+x(2).^4; % just for example
    options= optimset('OutputFcn',@outfun); % set the output function
    x= fminunc(f,[1 1],options);
    disp(grad_array);

    function stop = outfun(x, optimValues, state)
        grad_array(end+1,:)= optimValues.gradient;
        stop= false;
    end
end
```